# Improperly Paired Functions Example

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

From page 41 of this document: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/download/attachments/40402999/04+Dynamic+Memory.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1267372189000

Why is the delete below incorrect?

```
ip= static_cast<int*>malloc(sizeof(int));
*ip= 12;
. . .
delete ip; // wrong!
```

Comment: Slide 40 of the presentation you linked really couldn't be much clearer.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around the expression to cast.

Comment: I think the OP's question is "why is this a security vulnerability" at stated on slide 40.

Comment: @Seb Thankyou thats very helpful. @ Joa , it was a copy and paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `free()` for releasing memory acquired with `malloc()`.

The `delete` operator is only for `new`.

So, either

```
ip= static_cast<int*>malloc(sizeof(int));
*ip= 12;
. . .
free(ip);
```

or

```
ip= new int;
*ip= 12;
. . .
delete ip;
ip = 0;
```

Note that it's a good idea to nullify a deleted pointer after it's released, so that any attempt to incorrectly dereference it in future will be guaranteed to fail and will make the bug easier to locate.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` should be paired with `free`, and `new` should be paired with `delete`. `delete` will do some extra things that `free` doesn't (such as calling destructors), so using it to free memory allocated with `malloc` can be bad.